# How to get current domain user address,city,postal code details in vb.net windows application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to get current logged user address,city,postal code details from my user account.

now am logged with domain user, now i got my username, display name, email address. but i need user address, postal code,city, state also. so how can i get this via vb.net code or else c#.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Where is the above information stored?

Comment: now am logged with domain user, now i got my username, display name, email address. but i need user address, postal code,city, state also. so how can i get this via vb.net code or else c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information that you're talking about is not available on the UserPrincipal object in Active Directory.  See [UserPrincipal Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you're talking about getting this information from somewhere else, then you'll have to tell us where it is.

Comment: using "User principal properties"  we can get only username,middle name, surname, email address only but i need to get address,city,state,postal details also

Comment: I am telling you that the information you are looking for is not stored in Active Directory, and you cannot get it unless your network admins have extended AD with additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but just in case it could help someone else. You can get all AD User properties using the [DirectoryEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry?view=netframework-4.7.2) object instead of UserPrincipal.

Here is a snippet in C# for getting properties using both UserPrincipal and DirectoryEntries, but I think you can easily rewrite in VB.NET

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, server, username, password);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context);
userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = userPrincipalName;

PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);
UserPrincipal foundUserPrincipal = (UserPrincipal)searcher.FindOne();
searcher.Dispose();

if (foundUserPrincipal != null)
{
    string ldapUserPath = $"LDAP://{server}/{foundUserPrincipal.DistinguishedName}"
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntryUser = new DirectoryEntry(ldapUserPath, username, password);
    Console.Write($"Postal Code: {directoryEntryUser.properties["PostalCode"].value}");
    Console.Write($"City: {directoryEntryUser.properties["l"].value}");
    Console.Write($"Address: {directoryEntryUser.properties["streetAddress"].value}");
}
```